# Can someone explain with example how recursion works with while loop?? I cant understand the flow

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

If there is a while loop inside a recursive function , will the loop exit once the function is called?

```
void RecFunction(something){
    cout<<"print something\n";
    while(somecondition)
    {
    RecFuntion(something)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tada, example: http://ideone.com/aVpAFB

Comment: If there is a while loop inside a non-recursive function, will the loop exit once the function is called? `void NonRecFunction() {cout << "print something\n"; while(somecondition) {NonRecFunction2(something);}}` Recursive function calls are ***not special***, they're just normal function calls, that happen to be to the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the call to `RecFunction` was a call to some other function; I assume you would have no problem seeing how that would work.  (And if you do, work that out before trying to tackle recursion.)  The logic would be the same even if the body of that other function were identical to that of `RecFunction`: you didn't need to know the inner workings of that function before, so it doesn't matter.

You can think of a recursive call as being just that: a call to some function which just happens to have the same name and body as the one making the call, but is otherwise completely different (it has its own parameters, local variables, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The first time `RecFunction` is called and the while loop is encountered, your code will keep calling `RecFunction`again again and again for as long as `somecondition` is `true`. Each of those recursive calls to `RecFunction` also comprises a while loop which will spawn more and more and more recursive calls to the same function each of which comprises a while loop which will spawn ... etc.. If `some condition` is always `true` your code will spawn an infinite number of function calls.

This code:

```
void RecFunction(int something) {
  std::cout<<something ;
  while(true) 
    RecFunction(something);
}

int main() {
  RecFunction(10);
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with clang results in this:

```
## ....
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
movl    -4(%rbp), %edi
callq   __Z11RecFunctioni
jmp LBB0_1
## ....
```

(move a value to a register, call RecFunction, repeat the last two steps again forever)

which will eventually crash of course..

Answer (score 0):

@Marinos K is correct. Basically the inner-most loop that is running will keep running until the right condition is met. This includes sub-routine calls embedded in loops. Make sure your 'for' and 'while' loops have a terminate by count or by time-out in case the proper condition is not met in a reasonable amount of time. It may return an error code, but at least your program will not hang-up. The more elaborate the code, the more sophisticated the error handlers will need to be. They can help point out un-responsive or irrational conditions.